# Opening Google Map containing directions and waypoints data in a native mobile app using JavaScript API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-urls

I'm using JavaScript Google Map API and Google Direction service for my website. I successfully managed to put around 100 waypoints on the Map. Now I want to open this map on a native mobile app Android and iOS if the user opens up the page on a mobile browser.

You can check my example [**here**](http://aucsol.com/projects/gmap-waypoints-v0.1/)

I want to open this Map as it is on a native Android and iOS app. To open it up on an Android device, I tried the following intent URI:

```
geo:latitude,longitude
```

The above [**intent**](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents) URI does not work in my case since there are a lot of waypoints latitude and longitude and above URI can have only one.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended and supported way to open native apps is using the [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide). The Google Maps URLs has a [Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) map action where you can specify origin, destination and waypoints (the number of supported waypoints vary by the platform).

You have to generate URI in form `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters` according to the documentation and use it with your intents.

I hope this helps!

Comment: this does not work for me since Google Maps URLs do not support my solution. For example, passing coordinates of around 100 waypoints as a query string results in showing up on a few on the native app as well as the website.

Comment: Yes, this is actually my requirement. I managed to generate 100 waypoints on the website using Google Map JavaScript API and Google direction service. I want to invoke the native mobile app with the same data (direction & waypoints) upon button tap if the user opens the page in the mobile browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, no way to pass hundred waypoints. You should reduce them to supported number.

Comment: Is there any possibility to pass a JSON file path in the URL to load the data through the Mobile app?

Comment: I'm not aware about such possibility.